# Как правильно реализовать регистрацию с подтверждением номера на laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, sms

Вопрос в загаловке, есть форма:

```
<form method="post" action="/register" id="form_register">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <label for="login">
                <p>Логин:</p>
                <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="" required>
            </label>
            <label for="password">
                <p>Пароль:</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" required>
            </label>
            <label for="password-confirmation">
                <p>Подтвердите пароль:</p>
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="" required>
            </label>
            <label for="phone">
                <p>Номер телефона:</p>
                <input id="send_sms" type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="8 999 999 99 99" maxlength ="11" required>
            </label>

            <input type="submit" name="regiser-sub" class="button" value="Зарегистрироваться">

            @include('sessions.errors')
        </form>
```

Контроллер

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view("sessions.create-user");
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'login' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,12|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,12',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:11',
        ]);

        $user = User::create(request(['login', 'password', 'phone']));
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect()->home();
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request){
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->home();
    }
}
```

Есть смс-шлюз который отправляет смс таким запросом https://g.s.ru/v2/sms/send?number=7999999999&text=F:+6844&sign=SMS
Собственно вопрос - нужно при заполнении поля "номер телефона" сделать аякс запрос на отдельный метод контроллера который будет получать номер введенный и формировать рандомный код, затем курлом отправлять этот код по смс и если код совпадает регистрировать пользователя? Ни разу такое не реализовавал, поэтому не знаю принцип, буду благодарен за подсказку как правильно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общая идея:

- создать случайный код
- сохранить в сессию
- выслать через смс
- при сохранении формы, обязательно, проверить введеный код с кодом который в сессии
- Создаешь обработчик в api.php. и контроллер, который будет отправлять через шлюз событие.

```
POST /api/register/send-sms

{
'phone': 799999999
}
```

- В форме для поля `phone` на подписываешься на событие `blur` получаешь содержимое поля `ajax` запросом на на адрес `/api/register/send-sms`.
- В контроллере генерируешь случайное число `23123`.
- Сохраняешь в session()->put('phone', '23123') - понадобится для валидации.
- Отправляешь через sms шлюз.

Но, в указанной выше форме нет поля ввода кода подтверждения и я бы добавил его в форму.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'login' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,12|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,12',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:11',
            'code_confirmation' => 'required|digits:5',
        ]);
```

Пользователь отправляет форму с кодом подтверждения. Валидация проверит что поля заполнены, но не проверит верность `code_confirmation` и здесь 2 пути:

В контроллере:

```
$code = session()->get($request->get('phone'));
if($code !== $request->get('code_confirmation')){
  // отправляешь код ошибки
}
```

Или в `ReqestForm`, но сути это не изменит. Подробнее можно найти в [документации.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook)

Я бы перенес все в `ReqestForm` для чистоты кода.